# Finding absolute elements with jQuery (perfomance)

Tags: jquery, performance

This script is returning all absolute positioned Elements inside a container. But as you might imagine, it slows down for a higher number of elements inside the container. Any suggestion for performance optimiziation? Maybe reducing the amount of elements to check before filtering?

```
absolutElements = $(container).find('*').filter(function () {
  return $(this).css('position') === 'absolute';  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gain [1-5% performance](http://jsperf.com/absolutely-absolute) using

`return 'absolute' === $(this).css('position');`

:)